# How to get the images from Yammer messages

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, yammer

Anyone know if it's possible to get the images linked with a message, the messages json returns the image url's but they can't be downloaded.

http://www.yammer.com/[group name]/api/v1/uploaded_files/12983399/preview/photo-1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try remove the group name and add access_token as a query string parameter:

```
http://www.yammer.com/api/v1/uploaded_files/12983399/preview/photo-1.jpg?access_token=sd9f8a08fas08df7
```